# Counting records from a table and writing the data into a text file in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

```
COMPANY_CODE    POLICY_NUMBER   AGENT   PLAN_CODE   AGENT_RANKING   SPLIT   STATUS
01                  001          100    ADV GOLD    1.0.0.0.0.0      0.3    BUYOUT
01                  001          101    ADV GOLD    1.1.0.0.0.0      0.5    LTCGPAY
01                  001          102    ADV GOLD    1.2.0.0.0.0      0.2    HPAY
```

These is a table called table2.

I have used these query:

```sql
select  'Pol_Number' as POL
union all 
select POLICY_NUMBER from day2
```

My objective is to write  these data into an .txt file  and if any of the condition does not match it will create a .txt file with size 0 kb

Comment: You can do this by creating a simple SSIS package where you use an OLE DB Source to read from the SQL Command you mentioned, and a Flat File Destination to export data to a Flat File, if no rows are exported an empty file will be created by default.

Comment: From the above SQL command,when there is no data, empty file has not been created as it have header as 'Pol'.I want a solution,if there is data in the table it will create a file with header and data,and if there is no data it will create a blank file without any header

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following SQL Command as source

```
select POLICY_NUMBER from day2
```

On the other hand, in the Flat File Connection Manager used by the destination, go to the advanced Tab and define only one column called `Pol_Number`.

For more information you can refer to the following official documentation:

- [Flat File Connection Manager Editor (Advanced Page)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/flat-file-connection-manager-editor-advanced-page?view=sql-server-2014)

Answer (score 0):

It got solved.What I did is that first I executed the query through DFT and stored the 
row count in  a variable(Row Count).Then,from that DFT i put the condition in precedence constraint(If Row Count==1,it will execute DFT2 otherwise if Rowcount>1 it will execute DFT 3).